# how to split a large file into smaller files for parallel processing in spring batch?

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch, partition

We have a large file which can be split logically (not be range but by the occurrence of next header record)

For example

HeaderRecord1
...large number of detail records
HeaderRecord2
...large number of detail records
and so on...

We want to split the file into multiple small files at the HeaderRecord level and process them in parallel.

How to achieve this in Spring Batch? When I google, I came across Systemcommandtasklet and to use Linux / Unix Split command to split.

Is that the best approach? Are there any partition options within Spring Batch?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom [`Partitioner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html) that calculates the indexes of each logical partition (begin/end index). Then use a custom item reader (that could extend `FlatFileItemReader`) which reads only the lines of the given partition (and ignore other lines).

Comment: I have implemented what you have mentioned above but, I'm getting `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Could not convert resource to file: [class path resource [input1.csv]]` error while writing to the output files. I have observed it happens only when I'm using `partitioner` works fine with just 'FlatFileItemWriter`. Any idea?